# UILabel in UITableHeaderView autoLayout not working for iPhone 6

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel, tableheader

I use autolayout for UILabel in TableHeaderView. The UILabel's height is not fixed, it is maybe single line or multi-line. I code this in ViewController:

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {
        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        var headerFrame = headerView.frame

        if height != headerFrame.size.height {
            headerFrame.size.height = height
            headerView.frame = headerFrame
            tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly on iPhone 5.  But, on iPhone 6, when the UILabel is single line, it disappears.

[image]

And it's error log here

```
    2015-11-22 16:50:42.338 Basket[11898:996678] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f97840bd210 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x7f9784072380(375)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f97840bd2b0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7f9784072380(363.5)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9784032650 UIImageView:0x7f97840705a0.width == 1.33333*UIImageView:0x7f97840705a0.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9784073a40 V:[UILabel:0x7f9784073e90'Funnybeer'(15)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9784128b40 V:[UILabel:0x7f9784128940'Nino Mamaladze'(15)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9784074d10 H:[UIImageView:0x7f97840705a0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f9784072380 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9784074d60 H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7f97840705a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f9784072380 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9784074e00 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7f97840705a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f9784072380 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9784074f40 V:[UIImageView:0x7f97840705a0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f9784073d20]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9784075080 V:[UIView:0x7f9784073d20]-(22)-[UILabel:0x7f9784073e90'Funnybeer']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9784075210 V:[UILabel:0x7f9784073e90'Funnybeer']-(3)-[UILabel:0x7f9784128940'Nino Mamaladze']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9784075260 V:[UILabel:0x7f9784074300'see you on friday :)']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f9784072380 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9784075350 'summary top distance' V:[UILabel:0x7f9784128940'Nino Mamaladze']-(10)-[UILabel:0x7f9784074300'see you on friday :)']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9781cf59f0 'tool height' V:[UIView:0x7f9784073d20(44)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9781cf59f0 'tool height' V:[UIView:0x7f9784073d20(44)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

My storyboard here[image]
Someone can help me?

Comment: There's not much to see, only that it might be caused because of the first two lines with NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint. Is there any view that's using auto layout without setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO?

Comment: I add constraints for UILabel in storyboard, just pin without size. do I have to setup UILabel translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO in code?

Comment: No that's taken care of, I think you can fix it with dasdom's answer.

Comment: @RickvanderLinde Unfortunately, it doesn't work. My question isn't UILabel resize tableHeaderView, please look the image in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Marco Arment has a [great gist](https://gist.github.com/marcoarment/1105553afba6b4900c10) about how to do this.

Comment: It's not working. I said, iPhone 5 works great, iPhone 6 not work. Please look the image in my question.